# Mockito mock with constructor parameter

Tags: testing, mockito

I am using mockito 1.9.5 and wanting to test a class that i have posted on github.

The issue is that I need to mock the `getStringFromExternalSources` method.

MyClass [code](https://github.com/svsvenu/poc/blob/master/mockito/src/main/java/com/venu/MyClass.java):

```
public class MyClass {

    String a,b,c;

    public MyClass(String a, String b, String c) {

        this.a = a;
        this.b =  b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String  executeLogic (String d) {

        return a + b + c + d;
    }

    public String getStringFromExternalSources (){
        return "i got it from some place else";
    }

}
```

My [current test](https://github.com/svsvenu/poc/blob/master/mockito/src/test/java/com/venu/MyClassTest.java):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {


    @Test
    public void MyClassTest() {

        MyClass mc = Mockito.spy(new MyClass("a","b","c") );

        Mockito.doReturn("mock").when(mc.executeLogic("real"));

        Mockito.doReturn("externalString").when(mc.getStringFromExternalSources());

        System.out.println(mc.executeLogic("real"));

    }

}
```

Any pointers ?

Comment: Can you share your attempt to spy the class?

Comment: Added the test, i need to some how add my instance variables to the mock object, if its possible

Comment: If you want to test a class, then don't mock it. Mocking is useful to provide mock **dependencies** to the class under test. If you mock the class you test, you test Mockito, not your code.

Comment: What exactly do you need to mock? Why not just create an instance and run the logic?

Comment: Sorry having isssues with the post, let me know if my new attempt is clear

Answer (score 3):

You can mock any method using when().thenReturn() construct.

```
Example:

    MyClass mc = Mockito.spy(new MyClass("a","b","c"));

    when(mc.getStringFromExternalSource()).thenReturn("I got it from there!!");
```

So whenever the method  *'getStringFromExternalSource()'* is invoked for the mocked object *mc* then it will return *"I got it from there!!"*.

if you want to Test class with different parameters then you can use *@Parameters annotation* to provide parameters to the class in conjunction with Parameterized runner and mention the parameters in a *public static method with `@Paramters` annotation*. A rough example would be:

```
 @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
 class SomeTestClass{

    @Mock
    SomeTestClass mSomeTestClassInstance;

    @Parameters
    public static Object provideParameters() {
        Object[] objects =   new Object[]{
                0,
                0,
                2
        };
      return objects;
    }
    public SomeTestClass(Object argument1){
    mArgument1 = argument1; 
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod{
     Object returnValue = mSomeTestClassInstance.testSomeMethod(mArgument1);
     assertequals(mArgument1,returnValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to mock `getStringFromExternalSources` method:

```
public class MyClassTest {

    @Test
    public void MyClassTest() {

        MyClass mc = mock(MyClass.class);
        when(mc.executeLogic("real").thenReturn("mock");
        when(mc.getStringFromExternalSources().thenReturn("externalString");

        System.out.println(mc.executeLogic("real"));
    }

}
```